# Selenium XPath logical AND joining multiple contains() filters?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to locate the below element using Selenium:

```
<a class="ABC" href="#" data-test-id="XXX|YYY|ZZZ">
```

There are multiple elements on the page with "ABC", "XXX", "YYY" and "ZZZ", but my key words are "ABC" and "ZZZ". So in order to target this element precisely, I need to write something like:

```
//input[@class="ABC"] AND //*[contains(@data-test-id,'ZZZ')]")
```

Is there a way to write this in a single XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either Following Xpath Or css selector.

**Xpath:**

```
//a[@class='ABC' and contains(@data-test-id,'ZZZ')]
```

**Css Selector:**

```
a.ABC[data-test-id*='ZZZ']
```

Comment: Thank you - I used the XPath option and it worked!  I couldn't find a good resource to read on the relevant syntaxis - could you possibly direct me?

Comment: You can learn it from Edureka.However there are many blogs and websites available if you google it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write compound predicates in XPath as follows:

```
//a[@class='ABC' and contains(@data-test-id,'ZZZ')]
```

or

```
//a[@class='ABC'][contains(@data-test-id,'ZZZ')]
```

Be careful with `contains()` as its substring testing can yield false positives: `ZZZ` is also a substring of `ZZZZ`, for example.  This more elaborate test can avoid the problem for delimited values such as you have with `|`:

```
//a[@class='ABC'][contains(concat('|',@data-test-id,'|'), '|ZZZ|')]
```

Comment: ...and of course a similar idiom can be applied to the space-delimited `@class` attribute if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I just had to replace 'input' with 'a'! I couldn't find a good resource to read on the relevant syntaxis - could you possibly direct me?

Comment: I updated the answer to use `a` rather than `input`.  (Sorry, I had looked at your original XPath rather than your original markup example.)

Comment: The original [XPath 1.0 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) is remarkably readable and a good place to start before progressing to the advances available in XPath 2.0 and 3.0+.  If you prefer a book, get a copy of Michael Kay's XSLT book that covers XPath too.

Comment: @kjhughes I have edited the double quotes to single quotes for uniformity. Let me know if the edit is fine with you.

Comment: @DebanjanB, oh, yes, of course it's fine with me.  Thank you!   ...and I see you missed a pair intentionally just so I wouldn't feel bad.  ;-)   Fixed those.  Thanks again.